# Google map marker title not display

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am displaying multiple google map marker and single marker which comes in loop. I have two issue :

1. Marker does not display title
2. When single marker comes, zoom not working.

Please check following link.

http://maplepress.co.in/distributers

Please select state (Delhi) in dropdown and select city(Daryaganj and Shahdara(its have single marker))

My code is :

```
    <script>
    window.onload = function () { 
    var mapOptions = { 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.6410857, 77.2414835), zoom:8, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions); 
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); var lat_lng = new Array(); 
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); for (i = 0; i ' + 
data.title + 'Address : ' + data.address + 'Phone : ' + data.phone ); infoWindow.open(map, marker); 
     }); 
  })(marker, data); 
} 

map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter()); 
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds); 
$("#maplemap").css({"display":"none"}); 
$("#dvMap").css({"display":"block"}); }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache, i can perfectly see the three markers in Daryaganj.

Comment: but not display marker name like google map iframe display name of marker. When you open page, you have see "Maple Press Pvt. Ltd." on map

Comment: Maple Press Pvt. Ltd.  in red color